# joining on null to find missing elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of int called MyList; it comes as the result of a linq to sql query.
I have a list of MyObject called ExistingObjectsList that contains an int as one of its properties.

I'm looking to create a new list that contains all the ints that are in MyObjectsList but not in MyList.

This is what I have so far:

```
var NewObjects = (from obj in MyObjectsList
                  join x in ExistingObjectsList on
                  obj.ID equals x into outer
                  from o in outer
                  where o == null
                  select o).ToList();
```

I'm sure it's simple but at the moment it's not working.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You want the objects from MyObjectsList or ExistingObjectsList?

Comment: Did you try using a Union and getting the distinct objects. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var NewObjects = ExistingObjectsList.Where(i => !MyObjectsList.Any(o => o.ID == i);
```

In you question you mention `ExistingObjectsList that contains an int as one of its properties` but it's not used in you sample query but if that is the case then instead of `o => o.ID == i` use `o => o.ID == i.thatPropery`

Comment: It's compiling but it's returning 0 and I know there are supposed to be 14 elements based on the sample data I'm working with.

Comment: ok, I fixed it; it was o => o == i.ID . Your answer is really elegant; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're searching for and *almost* have implemented correctly is the outer join. With slight modifications, your code can work to this end for your list of objects against your list of (presumably) integers.

```
var NewObjects = (from obj in MyObjectsList
        join x in ExistingObjectsList.Cast<int?>() on // changed here
        obj.ID equals x into outer
        from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty() // and here
        where o == null
        select obj).ToList(); // and here
```